# How do you get some value in the the middle of userInput

Tags: javascript

For example, I just want to get the ID which is at the end How do I do that?

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
function ()
}
var userInput = document.getElementById("1").value;
window.alert("Your id is " + userInput
{
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="1" type="text" value="my id is 1743876">
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Will the value always be that format?  If so, split will work.  Otherwise, a regex may be the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById("1").value.split(' ').pop();` should do it.

`split(' ')` breaks a string up into an array of strings using the delimiter you pass it (in this case a space: `' '`).

`pop()` returns the last element of an array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop

As [Gary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/731314/gary) said, for more complex needs, you should use a regular expression function like `match()`.

```
var matches = document.getElementById("1").value.match(/(\d+)/);
matches[0]; // contains the match
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Answer (score 0):

To extract the id from the string value you should use a regular expression.

In the case you know the exact amount of numbers/digits in the ID you could use a regular expression like this one `/\b\d{11}\b/g`

```
var userInput = document.getElementById("1").value.match(/\b\d{11}\b/g);
```

In the case you know the ID will vary between 9 and 11 digits you could use a regular expression like this one `/\b\d{9,11}\b/g`

```
var userInput = document.getElementById("1").value.match(/\b\d{9,11}\b/g);
```

So it doesn't matter where the ID goes in the string, you will always get it.